# two ggplots on one

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two ggplots. Can I somehow paint them on one picture? One as a background of another
My code :

```
ggplot(data = dd, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
+     geom_point(colour="red", size = 3, aes(alpha=col))
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_segment(aes(xend=x+dx, yend=y+dy), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3,"cm")))
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be much easier if you had asked this as one question instead of 3 separate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ggplot2 you can plot data from different sources by specifying a different `data` argument to your different `geom_*`. Something like :

```
library(grid)
df <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10),dx=rnorm(10),dy=rnorm(10))
dd <- data.frame(x=runif(15), y=runif(15))
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=dd, aes(x=x, y=y), col="red") +
  geom_segment(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=x+dx, yend=y+dy), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3,"cm")))
```

[image]

Is this what you are trying to do ?

Comment: @user2080209, I don't quite understand. How are you generating your second set of points to use `geom_segment` to create a vector field? Are you randomly creating points as shown here by juba using `rnorm`? That would a random direction to the vector fields...

Comment: I have a text file. There are written my x,y,dx,dy. I don't generate them randomly